# How to set focus on specific cell in onSelectRow in inline edit jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, focus

How to set focus on specific cell in onSelectRow in inline edit jqgrid?

I have tried the answers from:
1. [Need jqGrid inline editing to have focus go to clicked cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161953/need-jqgrid-inline-editing-to-have-focus-go-to-clicked-cell)
2. [How to set focus to cell which was clicked to start inline edit in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219598/how-to-set-focus-to-cell-which-was-clicked-to-start-inline-edit-in-jqgrid)
3. [How to edit the selected cell on jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536654/how-to-edit-the-selected-cell-on-jqgrid/6538102#6538102)
4. [Set the focus to the editable input field on select row in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825722/set-the-focus-to-the-editable-input-field-on-select-row-in-jqgrid)

but none of that works!

So now I don't need to find what cell the user clicked, but I need the cursor to be exactly in "lg_description" column for each row. Which I guess the problem is with the e parameter, and I think when I set it to "lg_description" column, I just need to attach "lg_description" somewhere instead of e parameter.

**EDITED:**
This is my code:

```
onSelectRow: function(id, status, e){
    var grid = $(this); 
    if(id && id!==lastSel){               
        grid.restoreRow(lastSel);   
        lastSel=id;

        //cursor focus

        //first attemp: $("#lg_description").focus();
        //second attemp: $("input, select",e.target).focus();
        //third attemp: document.getElementById("lg_description").focus();
        //fourth attemp:
        /*var setFocusToCell = function(e) {
            if(!e || !e.target) return;
            var $td = $(e.target).closest("td"), $tr = $td.closest("tr.jqgrow"), ci, ri, rows = this.rows;
            if ($td.length === 0 || $tr.length === 0 || !rows) return;
            ci = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($td[0]);
            ri = $tr[0].rowIndex;
            $(rows[ri].cells[ci]).find("input,select").focus();
        }
        setFocusToCell(e);*/
    }
    grid.editRow(id, true,"","","","",aftersavefunc);  
    //fifth attemp: grid.editRow(id, true,function() {$("#lg_description").focus();},"","","",aftersavefunc);
 },
```

I have tried 5 different attemps where the fifth one is a substitute for the code above it

Comment: You wrote that none from above suggestions not works. If you double-click on some cell in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithInlineEditingFocus.htm) you don't have focus in the clicked cell? Or your mean that *your code* based on the suggestion not works? Could you include the code of your accempts? You wrote about `lg_description`. Where is the corresponding code? Do you tried to place `.focus()` call inside of `setTimeout()`? Typically the setting of focus with small timeout work always.

Comment: I mean that my code based on the suggestions didn't work. I've edited my questions to attach the code

Comment: you makes many attempts to set focus **before** calling of `editRow` which *creates* the input fields if inline editing. Moreover I asked you to insert more full code which you use. It's strange *why* you try to use `$("#lg_description").focus();` with `lg_description` to set the focus. Is the rowid of the editing row `lg`? Is the column name is `description`? Could you include more full code which you use? At least `colModel` and test data for the grid (2 rows are enough) are required.

Comment: lg_description is the column name and index from the col model. Oh I see, so we must call the editRow first before we can set the focus on specific cell. So I tried to implement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536654/how-to-edit-the-selected-cell-on-jqgrid/6538102#6538102 code again, and it works! I don't know why I failed on my attempts before. Thanks Oleg!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You makes many attempts to set focus **before** calling of `editRow` which creates the input fields if inline editing. Moreover it's strange why you try to use

```js
$("#lg_description").focus();
```

with `id="lg_description"` to set the focus. Is the rowid of the editing row `"lg"`? Is the column name is `"description"`? [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithInlineEditingFocus.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6538102/315935) which you referenced set focus on the `<input>` or `<select>` in the clicked cell (children of `e.target`). If you want to set the focus always on specific column then you should use

```js
$("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(id) + "_lg_description").focus();
// where "lg_description" is the column name
```

The usage of `$.jgrid.jqID(id)` instead of `id` is more safe, because id could have in common case meta-characters which have to be escaped in the selector. See [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more details.

Comment: hey I try this and it works with Id "#"+id+"_description" after the id there should be underscore I think. isn't it?

Comment: @DilanG: Yes. jqGrid uses internal function `$.jgrid.createEl` to create input/select elements used for editing or searching. Inline editing for example uses `rowid + "_" + columnName` to build the id of the editing field (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L80)).

Comment: I mentioned that because you missed it above answer.it isn't a big issue. anyway I edited the answer and thank you for the answer.

Comment: @DilanG: I agree that it's better to fix the code in the answer and not only in the comment. Thanks!